# Using negative-lookahead (or lookbehind?) to extract column names from SQL

Tags: c#, regex

I have a long SQL script and I want to identify occurrences of SQL column names and replace them with entries from a dictionary, however I want to preserve parameter names.

A column name has the form `schema.TableName.ColumnName`, `TableName.ColumnName` or just `ColumnName`. Whereas parameter names always have the form `@parameterName`.

So given this script (contrived example):

```
DECLARE @foo varchar(max) = '123'
DECLARE @bar varchar(max) = '456'
SELECT foo, table.bar, @bar FROM table ORDER BY table.foo DESC
```

I want to match:

```
foo
table.bar
table
table.foo
```

I first wrote a simple regex to match column names:

```
([A-Za-z_]+[0-9A-Za-z_]*)(\.[A-Za-z_]+[0-9A-Za-z_])*(\.[A-Za-z_]+[0-9A-Za-z_])*
```

(It's a bit of a hack as it builds left-to-right, so the first matched group is either the column-name (if single-labelled), the table-name (if double-labelled), or the schema name (if fully-qualified), but this isn't a huge problem).

...except this regex also selects the portion of parameters immediately after the at-symbol. So I need to modify it so it doesn't match parameters. I added a negative-lookbehind assertion `(?<!\@)` to match the leading `@` prefix and to then cancel the match, however it doesn't work:

```
((?<!\@)([A-Za-z_]+[0-9A-Za-z_]*)(\.[A-Za-z_]+[0-9A-Za-z_])*(\.[A-Za-z_]+[0-9A-Za-z_])*
```

Despite the negative-lookbehind assertion, given the input "`@foobar`" it matches/captures "`@f[oobar]`" instead of refusing to capture it at all.

Obviously I'm not using the lookbehind assertion correctly. I've tried placing the assertion in and outside of the parent group and also tried the negative-lookahead assertion, to no effect.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I'm doing this outside of SQL, in C#/.NET regular expressions in-fact. It's a program that will process a schema+sproc dump of the database.

Answer (score 1):

As far as fixing your expression, you are missing a \b to show that we are at the beginning of the word.

```
(?<!@)\b([A-Za-z_]+\w*)(\.[A-Za-z_]+\w*)*\b
```

That will match

```
'SELECT', 'foo', 'table.bar', 'FROM', 'table', 'ORDER', 'BY', 'table.foo', 'DESC'
```

From the statement

```
SELECT foo, table.bar, @bar FROM table ORDER BY table.foo DESC
```

I do feel that regex alone may not be the best solution for this.
It may be better to try and find a sql parser or write a simple one, replacing column names as you encounter them.